# StoreKit + SwiftUI Previews - No such module '_StoreKit_SwiftUI'

Tags: xcode, swiftui, storekit

After I added Storekit to my App SwiftUI-Previews doesn't work anymore. The App itself builds like a charm but all the Previews are broken with the following Error Message:
Code Block

```
No such module '_StoreKit_SwiftUI'
```

Does anyone else knows this issues and has an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure how to solve the problem, but i've seen some other people having this same issue too. Saying this so you can at least know that this is most likely a bug, and not your fault.

Comment: I don't think it should be expected to work in Preview, Preview is definitely not for that (receipts management, transactions processing, etc., etc.). It is a feature, like Phone or AR, but Preview is *just for UI Preview*.

Comment: Ok, so maybe the best solution is to move all the StoreKit related code to a separate Component so the view won't know anything about StoreKit. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well in my project, but don't know yet how to solve it. I'm seeing this only in the Xcode 12 betas. In Xcode 11 it works fine for me. In which Xcode version do you have this issue?

Comment: This seems to be an Xcode 12 bug indeed. I just created a fresh SwiftUI iOS project and the preview runs fine. As soon as I import StoreKit, I get `No such module '_StoreKit_SwiftUI'`. This error occurs, no matter where you import StoreKit, wether it's in the same file as one of your previews or any other file in the same target. This should definitely work, as it worked in Xcode 11 already and it's pretty common for apps to use StoreKit and SwiftUI previews in the same target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a temporary fix for Xcode 12 Beta 5. Hopefully it will be fixed in the next version so it can be removed.

Add the following to your build settings:

```
Architectures
    Excluded Architectures
        Debug
            Simulator - iOS 14.0 SDK arm64
```

Thank you to:
https://twitter.com/brentdax/status/1297988060462759936

Comment: this bug is still present for pods (Xcode 12.4)